# Linux gateway forwarding issue

Tags: linux, adsl

how do I enable packet forwarding for an ethernet dsl modem? Must this be done with iptables?

Comment: Why did you remove 95% of your question? You've removed all the useful information and made it harder to answer for your specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

You enable packet forwarding on a Linux (2.6.x kernel) router by executing the following command as root ...

```
# echo "1" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

You will need to execute this command every time you start/reboot your machine.  Add the command to your equivalent of /etc/rc.local so that it is automatically executed for you.

Comment: or put "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" in /etc/sysctl.conf, which is the easiest way of setting values in proc.

Answer (score 1):

Log in as root.
Type the following exactly as it appears

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then type this exactly as it appears

```
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

The first line sets packet forwarding in the kernel; the second line ensures that it survives a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is an DSL router presented as an ethernet device. Are you able to ping the internal interface of the router? If not, there's a configuration problem on the lan side of the device.

Does the router have diagnostic tools built in? Can you ping out from the router? Can you ping an internal device? If you can, then the problem lies in the forwarding between the two interfaces. It could be a firewall or a possible NAT problem.

If you can't ping out, then there is a problem with the DSL connection. If you can't ping in, then there's a problem with the LAN interface.

Comment: I can ping the address on ppp0, just not the isp

Comment: Is this a USB or Ethernet modem?

Comment: ethernet modem..

Comment: It hasn't logged onto your ISP properly, I'm guessing it hasn't been given the external gateway address. Use it's admin screen to disconnect and then reconnect.

Comment: Yes, it would appear that some settings were not correctly set on the new modem. I'd contact the ISP support and get them to help you check all your settings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, `iptables` won't help you.  It sounds like you can ping your ethernet router, but nothing beyond it.  To figure this out, you need to tell us what router model you have and whether you have static or dynamic IP addresses.